# Have a lot final strings, what do you recommend to place them in java?

Tags: java

Want to create a seperate class and store all the strings inside it. Is this a way good or there is better way?

Comment: You need to provide some information on the nature and purpose of these Strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really comes back to what those strings are for. For example if they contain what are effective static constants they might be best placed inside the classes that require them. Or if used by a number of classes perhaps enums might be a better solution because it allows you to group and effectively type them.

Then you have to consider if they are strings that the users will see. In that case you may need to store them in properties file or even a database. Especially if you want to allow for internationalisation at some point in the future.

Comment: And if localization may be required, your IDE may help prepare those properties files -- e.g., Eclipse provides "Externalize Strings."

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives: Put them on disk and read them on demand, put them as constants into an interface, use enums instead.
What are you doing with the strings?

Comment: is there advantage to use enums?

Comment: Constants in an interface are not a good idea, don't use that. Interfaces are supposed to describe the behavior of an object, that has nothing to do with constants it might need. See here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=32

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use **ResourceBundle** or **Properties**.

```
public class TestResource extends ListResourceBundle{
   public Object[][] getContents() {
       Object [][]mydata={ {"key1","Data1"}, {"key2","Data2"}};
       return mydata;
   }
}

public class Resx{

  public static void main(String []args) {

    try{

      ResourceBundle rb=ResourceBundle.getBundle("TestResource");

      Enumeration e=rb.getKeys();
      String key;

      while(e.hasMoreElements()){
          key=(String) e.nextElement();
          System.out.println(key + " " + rb.getObject(key));
      }
    }catch(Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never had a program where it would have made sense to store all Strings in a separate file.

- Strings are part of self-documenting code.
- Putting all strings in a central file breaks modularisation

Comment: Yes, and when I remember correctly, I didn't put all the String constants in one big class. Did you? And did the TO talk about i18n? I didn't had the feeling.